# Issue in ADO-excel, SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, ado, vba

SQL query in ado work fine only if the `Sect` column present in ADODC1 sheet.
If the ADODC1 sheet not have `Sect` column it throws error.
Pls correct my below query...

```
strSQL = "Select Name,Dept,IIF(ISNULL(Sect),'',Sect) AS Sect from [Adodc1$] UNION Select Name,Dept,Sect from [Adodc2$];"
```

If the `Sect` column not present in ADODC1 Sheet, need the results as empty.

Comment: You could always run a "select * from adodc1$ Where 1=2" first: that will allow you to check the field names in the returned empty recordset for the required column before running your main query.

Comment: @Tim I wish you would post that as an answer.

Comment: @Remou: see related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean by "need the results as empty". If you fail over the error you will get a closed recordset. Is that 'empty'?

I suspect this is what you need to do (pseudo code):

```
On Error Resume Next
strSQL = "Select Name,Dept,IIF(ISNULL(Sect),'',Sect) AS Sect from [Adodc1$]" & _
             " UNION Select Name,Dept,Sect from [Adodc2$];"

Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)

If rs.State <> adStateOpen Then

  strSQL = "Select Name,Dept,NULL AS Sect from [Adodc1$]" & _
             " UNION Select Name,Dept,Sect from [Adodc2$];"

  Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)

    If rs.State <> adStateOpen Then

        ' Deeper problems...
```